# Custom Cloudwatch Metrics

Tags: amazon-rds, amazon-cloudwatch

I am using AWS RDS SQL server and I need to do enhanced level monitoring via Cloudwatch. By default there are some basic monitoring available but I want use custom metrics as well.

In my scenario I need to create an alarm whenever we get more number of deadlock in SQL server. We are able to fetch the details of deadlock via script and I need to prepare custom metrics for the same.

Can any one help on this or kindly suggest any alternate solution?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: It's quite simple -- whatever app/script you use to collect the data should send the data to Amazon CloudWatch as a custom metric. See the AWS documentation for SDKs for many popular programming languages. If you have difficulty writing the code, please post a question with your code and a description of the problem you are experiencing.

Comment: Thanks for your response John. Can you help me on any costume metric references for this scenario, so I can understand more clearly.

Comment: can you provide some insight into how  you get to know the deadlocks and the corresponding information for debugging?